# Use a WITH in an SQL function?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, function, with-statement

I'm trying to make a function but I do not know how to get the `WITH` in it. Here is my code.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CubicVolume  (@StartDate date, @EndDate date) RETURNS @TableDays TABLE
(Days int)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT @TableDays
       WITH Dates AS  (
                SELECT @StartDate AS DayInQuestion
                    UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(Day, 1, DayInQuestion) AS DayInQuestion
                    FROM Dates AS Dates
                    WHERE (DayInQuestion < @EndDate)
                )
    SELECT DISTINCT count(Dates.DayInQuestion)
        FROM Dates AS Dates LEFT OUTER JOIN
        HEATHrs ON Dates.DayInQuestion = HEATHrs.StartDate
        WHERE        (CAST(DATEPART(weekday, Dates.DayInQuestion) AS int) BETWEEN 2 AND 6)
   RETURN
END
```

Comment: What do you mean "get the with in it"?

Comment: In SQL Server, the `with` goes before the `insert`.  This is not true in all databases.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the Common Table Expression (CTE) before the `INSERT`:

```
WITH Dates AS  
(
    SELECT @StartDate AS DayInQuestion
        UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(Day, 1, DayInQuestion) AS DayInQuestion
        FROM Dates AS Dates
        WHERE (DayInQuestion < @EndDate)
)
INSERT @TableDays
SELECT DISTINCT count(Dates.DayInQuestion)
    FROM Dates AS Dates LEFT OUTER JOIN
    HEATHrs ON Dates.DayInQuestion = HEATHrs.StartDate
    WHERE        (CAST(DATEPART(weekday, Dates.DayInQuestion) AS int) BETWEEN 2 AND 6)
```